# VBA method 'range of object' _Worksheet failed variables used in range declaration

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am getting the following error message: `Method range of object _worksheet failed` when trying to select a range in excel using variables as range length.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
Private Function copyAmount(startRange As Integer, endRange As Integer)
    Dim startRng As String
    Dim endRng As String

    startRng = "A" & Str(startRange)
    endRng = "A" & Str(endRange)

    activateBook ("book2.xlsm")
    Set rng = Range(startRng, endRng)
    Workbooks("book2.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range(rng).Select
    Selection.Copy
    activateBook ("Book1.xlsm")
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The particular error you have won't happen if you replace `Range(rng).Select` with `rng.Select` (i.e. it is *already* a `Range`) assuming `rng` has been defined as a `Range` variable in MS Excel 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are not fully qualifying your ranges. Also it is not necessary to activate a workbook to do a copy paste :) Also you do not need a `Function` for this. Use a `Sub`

**CODE**

```
Private Sub copyAmount(startRange As Integer, endRange As Integer)
    Dim wbT As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set wbT = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbO = Workbooks("book2.xlsm")
    
    Set rng = wbO.Sheets(1).Range("A" & startRange & ":" & "A" & endRange)
    rng.Copy
    
    '~~> Change Sheets(1) below to the relevant sheet
    wbT.Sheets(1).Range("D3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

`Sub`, like a `Function` procedure, is a separate procedure that can take arguments, perform a series of statements, and change the value of its arguments. However a `Sub` procedure doesn't return a value like a `Function` does.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Str`, use `Cstr`. This will make your code work I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error when your code is in a worksheet and not a module.